# サービスの自動起動を止めたい

Tags: linux, debian, webrtc

WebRTCに関連するuv4l等をインストールしたところ、uv4l-uvcデーモンが自動起動されるようになりました。
この自動起動を、止めたいのですがどこで起動されているのかが分かりません。

/etc/inidt.dにはuv4l_uvcのスクリプトはあります。
しかし、ls rc*.d -l | grep uv4l_uvc　を打っても何も表示されません。
また、uv4l_uvcスクリプト内にremoveがあったので、実行してみましたが、やはり自動起動は止まりませんでした。

uv4l_vucは、どこから起動されているのでしょうか？
或いは、サービスの起動シーケンスはどのように調べれば良いでしょうか？
OSはDebian 9です

Comment: 有効になっている自動起動サービス一覧は次のコマンドでも調べられます。：`systemctl list-unit-files -t service|grep enabled`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## サービスの自動起動を止める

> OSはDebian 9

systemdでサービスが管理されているはずなので、

```
sudo systemctl stop uv4l.service
sudo systemctl disable uv4l.service
```

でいかがでしょうか。

## サービスの起動シーケンスを調べる

systemdのユニットファイルが格納されているパスの一覧は、以下のコマンドにより表示することができます。

```
systemctl show --property=UnitPath
```

表示されるパスのいずれかに`uv4l.service`というファイルが含まれているはずですので、そちらの中身からサービスの起動シーケンスについて調べられます。